# How to find uppper bound for the hyper parameters in linear model?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have a loss function of the following form:

$$\arg\min_w= \|Y-w^TX\|_2^2 + \lambda\|w\|_1 + \gamma \sum_{g=1}^G\|w_g\|_1$$

where $w_g$ is a group of coefficients.
Given $Y$ and $X$, I would like to find upper bound for $\lambda$ and/or $\gamma$ that will set all weights ($w$) to zero.
can anyone help me how to drive such upper bound for this loss function?

Comment: This is a community. May I suggest to go over your former questions and indicate which answers you accept, and  which answers were not satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

In the lasso-problem a parameter $\lambda \ge \|X^T Y\|_\infty$ will set all regression coefficients to zero. See, for example, page 813 of

> Dossal, Charles, et al. "The degrees of freedom of the Lasso for
>   general design matrix." Statistica Sinica (2013): 809-828.

as a reference for this.